# Tizen - Angular - when focusing to input/caph-input keyboard is not appearing

Tags: angularjs, tizen, caph-framework

this is a self-answering question.
I got a problem and now solved it. If anybody get this problem, here is the problem:
When focusing to input/caph-input keyboard is not appearing

Answer (score 0):

Solution:
as default element.focus() is enough to show keyboard, but sometimes input element's style info filled with "-webkit-user-select: none" attribute. Before calling element.focus() you need to clear style